# jQuery addClass using input select

Tags: forms, select, addclass

Im a bit of a jQuery novice.

I have 5 options in a drop down menu.
I want to add a class in a div depending on which option is selected.
This class will then change the layout of the content using CSS.

Here is an example if it helps!

Thanks

```
<form>

<select>
<option id="1">layout 1</option>
<option id="2">layout 2</option>
<option id="3" selected>layout 3</option>
<option id="4">layout 4</option>
<option id="5">layout 5</option>
</select>

<div class="3">styled content</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ".attr()" to set the class attribute of the div onchange.
You're best to change the option **id** to **value** first. then:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   $("div").attr("class", $(this).val());
});
```

(EDIT) Change it to:

```
$("select#np_blog_layout").change(function() {
   $("div#changebox").attr("class", $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't have to use id to your options. Put the values in `value` attribute. Put ID to your div and select so you can select them using jQuery.

```
<form>

<select Id="selectElement">
<option value="1">layout 1</option>
<option value="2">layout 2</option>
<option value="3" selected>layout 3</option>
<option value="4">layout 4</option>
<option value="5">layout 5</option>
</select>

<div id="styledContent" class="3">styled content</div>

</form>
```

On JS

```
    //Attach event handler to select element's onchange event
$('#SelectElement').bind("change",changeStyle);

    //The event handler
function changeStyle()
{
       //Set class to selected value
   $('#styledContent').class($('#SelectElement').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What 'rudeovski ze bear' said, but if you still want to set it to the div's class to the selected elements id, here it is.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('div').attr('class', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```