# addclass with a select input

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add a class to a div. The name of ce class is an option of a select input.

```
<form onsubmit="return creationMessage(this)"
      target="_blank"
      name="NomForm"
      method="post"
      action="/posting.forum"
      id="am">

  <div class="fond">
    <div class="faction">Présentation</div>
    <select id="ttype" name="ttype" class="obligatoire" focus>
      <option>dresseur</option>
      <option>ligue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

And a simple block

```
<div class="faction"></div>
```

If the option "dresseur" is selected, I want this :

```
<div class="faction dresseur"></div>
```

I tried:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var colorSelect = $(this).val();
  $('.faction').addClass('colorSelect');
});
```

Comment: You need to post what you tried as well, otherwise it sounds like you want us to write code for you

Comment: Yes, sorry I wanted to make it less massive !

<pre>
<form onsubmit="return creationMessage(this)" target="_blank" name="NomForm" method="post" action="/posting.forum" id="am">     
<div class="fond">
    <div class="faction">Présentation</div>
    <select id="ttype" name="ttype" class="obligatoire" focus>        
      <option>dresseur</option>
      <option>ligue</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select').on('change', function() {
 var colorSelect = $(this).val(); 
        $('.faction').addClass('colorSelect');
});
</script>
</pre>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery addClass using input select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116387/jquery-addclass-using-input-select)

Comment: @j08691 I have been waiting for more than 10 min, he has not answered yet.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov So? No one is under a time obligation here.

Comment: Also, you need to add relevant code in the question, not as a comment

Comment: @j08691 it is not a question of time, It is the thing that I want to help to solve a problem, and if my solution is not working, I would like to get notified asap to help out. Hope this will makes clear =)

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov Have you posted a solution without knowing if it works?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I tried it on my own device of course, but maybe it is not working on his, and I'd like to know and help. Is my desire to help people is a problem?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov Ok, apologies. Just be patient and if your answer is good enough and correct, it will be noticed. :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava no problem, thanks =)

Comment: You need to use the variable `colorSelect`. The way you have used it is a string `'colorSelect'`. This is the right one: `$('.faction').addClass(colorSelect);`

Comment: Thanks for all the help ! I used the jquery soluce !

Answer (score 1):

simply that

```js
const amForm     = document.querySelector('form#am')
  ,   divFaction = amForm.querySelector('div.faction');

amForm.ttype.oninput = _ => divFaction.className = `faction ${amForm.ttype.value}`;
```

```css
.dresseur {color: red;}
.ligue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<form id="am" >

  <div class="faction">Présentation</div>

  <select name="ttype" class="obligatoire">
    <option value="dresseur">dresseur</option>
    <option value="ligue">ligue</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div class="faction"></div>
<select name="type" class="obligatoire">        
  <option selected="selected">dresseur</option>
  <option>ligue</option>
</select>
```

And in your JS file:

```
$(function(){

          var exist_val = $(".obligatoire").val();
          $(".faction").addClass(exist_val);


          $(".obligatoire").on('change', function(){
            var current_value = $(this).val();
            if(!$(".faction").hasClass(current_value)){
              $(".faction").addClass(current_value);
            }

          })

        });
```

What it does is takes selected value from the option and add it to a class name of div and if select value changes, it makes the same thing again.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I see the logic, so thanks !

Comment: @Desferale you are welcome! Please tick green the answer if it helps to solve your issue